# How to update multiple websites with same CMS?

Tags: asp.net, module, webforms, updates

I have a exclusive CMS developed in ASP.NET Webforms C# and uses SQL Server data base. There are more than 20 websites using this CMS.
Which is the best way for me to update all these websites, when I release a newer version of the CMS.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this the same way other updates are handled for many different pieces of software. For example, most software is shipped as a package of core files and folders. When the user installs the software, a separate folder is created on the machine for that installation, which contains all user-specific (or in your case, site-specific) information. When an update is released the installation script will replace the core files with the newly updated files, and leave the custom user-specific files untouched.

This, of course will be very easy to accomplish or very hard depending on how your CMS is built and how your users are using the software. If users are customizing (or 'hacking') your core files - they will lose all those customizations when the update is applied.

I suggest you look into installers or software package tools to help release the updates to your users. InstallShield is one that comes to mind. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. there is no customizing (or 'hacking'). all contents are is data base. i need to replace new files with the old ones.